# Customize sorting of Treeview

Tags: c#, winforms, sorting, treeview, icomparable

I have a treeview that need to be sorted according to the tag of every node and also according to the alpha beta.

for example:

- **Node1** , tag=**A** , text= *Apple*
- **Node2**, tag=**B** , text= *Baloon*
- **Node3**, tag=**A**, text= *Help*

I want to sort it, that nodes with tag A will be firsts, and just then nodes with tag B.
but, i want the nodes that contains tag A, to be sorted from A to Z.

(the order = **Node1,Node3,Node2**)

please help me , 
How can i do it?

thanks in advance!

Comment: just a clarification, do you have an header on the top to click once or twice and invert the sort order ASC and DERSC? I don't think so, the standard TreeView does not have the header if I recall right. In this case more than customize the sorting shouldn't we say we wont to generate/populate the treeview with a certain order?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you're talking about System.Windows.Forms.Treeview, you can use TreeViewNodeSorter and an implementation of IComparer to create a custom sorting strategy.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.treeview.treeviewnodesorter.aspx

Answer (score 0):

thanks! I did it like that:

```
 /// <summary>
        ///  Create a node sorter that implements the IComparer interface.
       /// </summary>
        public class NodeSorter : IComparer
        {
            // compare between two tree nodes
            public int Compare(object thisObj, object otherObj)
            {
                TreeNode thisNode = thisObj as TreeNode;
                TreeNode otherNode = otherObj as TreeNode;

                // Compare the types of the tags, returning the difference.
                if (thisNode.Tag is  first_type&& otherNode.Tag is another_type)
                    return 1;
                 //alphabetically sorting
                return thisNode.Text.CompareTo(otherNode.Text);
            }
        }
```